# Why does calling encodePassword() (or hashPasswor()) with identical salts and passwords produces diffent hashes in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, password-hash

In `UserPassword` [encoder](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/Encoder/UserPasswordEncoder.php),

```
public function encodePassword(UserInterface $user, string $plainPassword)
{
    $encoder = $this->encoderFactory->getEncoder($user);
    return $encoder->encodePassword($plainPassword, $user->getSalt());
}
```

encoder gets the salt from user entity.

I set a static variable to the `getSalt()` in User entity:

```
public function getSalt()
{
    return 'my-static-salt';
}
```

But when I encode:

```
$password  = $encoder->encodePassword($user, "my-password");
$password2 = $encoder->encodePassword($user, "my-password");
```

`$password` and `$password2` are different from each other as if the `encodePassword()` method uses a random salt.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note for Symfony > 5.4

From Symfony 6 these classes and methods are named more appropriately replacing `Encode` with `Hash`. And moved from the Security Core package to the Password Hasher package:

For example,
`Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory` becomes
`Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\PasswordHasherFactory`, and so on.

But the substance of the answer remains the same.

---

The `EncoderFactory` is, by default, giving you an instance of the `NativePasswordEncoder` (unless you have the libsodium library installed, in which case it would give you a `SodiumPasswordEncoder`).

If you look at  `NativePasswordEncoder::encodePassword()` you'll see [this](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/a8c67a8bc6bd8012c5d6b70cb030ca3422476caa/Encoder/NativePasswordEncoder.php#L60):

```
public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
{
    if (\strlen($raw) > self::MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException('Invalid password.');
    }

    // Ignore $salt, the auto-generated one is always the best

    $encoded = password_hash($raw, $this->algo, $this->options);

    if (72 < \strlen($raw) && 0 === strpos($encoded, '$2')) {
        // BCrypt encodes only the first 72 chars
        throw new BadCredentialsException('Invalid password.');
    }

    return $encoded;
}
```

Notice this comment:

> // Ignore $salt, the auto-generated one is always the best

If you do not pass a salt string to `password_hash()`, it will generate its own randomly generated salt each time you call it, and store the salt within the result of the operation (and the hashing algorithm used).

(Similarly, in `SodiumPasswordEncoder` you'll see that `$salt` [is not used at all](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/a8c67a8bc6bd8012c5d6b70cb030ca3422476caa/Encoder/SodiumPasswordEncoder.php#L57), although a similar comment does not exist).

Further reading:

- [New in Symfony 4.3: Native Password Encoder](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-native-password-encoder)
- [`password_hash()` docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/07-password-hashing.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For me, it's actually not that important to get the same password encode. The problem is, isPasswordValid returns false:
$encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $plainPassword)

Comment: OK, I found the answer for the second problem. It seems I call $user wrongly. Thank you.